# MongoDB aggregation counts based on value

Tags: mongodb

I have a MongoDB query I am trying to figure out.  I'd like to group my data by date and one other field (portfolio) and get the counts for each buildResult in that grouping.

Sample data looks like this:

```
    {
            "_id" : ObjectId("52dea764e4b0a491abb54102"),
            "type" : "build",
            "time" : ISODate("2014-01-21T16:59:16.642Z"),
            "data" : {
                    "buildNumber" : 35,
                    "buildDuration" : 1034300,
                    "portfolio" : "Shared",
                    "buildResult" : "FAILURE"
            }
    }
    {
            "_id" : ObjectId("52dea7b7e4b0a491abb54103"),
            "type" : "build",
            "time" : ISODate("2014-01-21T17:00:39.617Z"),
            "data" : {
                    "buildNumber" : 13,
                    "buildDuration" : 1186028,
                    "portfolio" : "Sample",
                    "buildResult" : "SUCCESS"
            }
    }
```

The output I am shooting for would be something like this:

```
    {
            "result" : [
                    {
                            "_id" : {
                                    "month" : 2,
                                    "day" : 28,
                                    "year" : 2014,
                                    "portfolio" : "Shared"
                            },
                            "aborted" : 3,
                            "failure" : 0,
                            "unstable" : 0,
                            "success" : 34
                    },
                    {
                            "_id" : {
                                    "month" : 2,
                                    "day" : 28,
                                    "year" : 2014,
                                    "portfolio" : "Sample"
                            },
                            "aborted" : 3,
                            "failure" : 2,
                            "unstable" : 0,
                            "success" : 37
                    }
            ],
            "ok" : 1
    }
```

My current query is:

```
db.builds.aggregate([    
    { $match: { "data.buildResult" : { $ne : null} }},
    { $group: {          
        _id: {              
            month: { $month: "$time" },             
            day: { $dayOfMonth: "$time" },             
            year: { $year: "$time" },   
            portfolio: "$data.portfolio",                    
        },         
        aborted: { $sum: { "$data.buildResult": "ABORTED" } },
        failure: { $sum: { "$data.buildResult": "FAILURE" } },
        unstable: { $sum: { "$data.buildResult": "UNSTABLE" } },
        success: { $sum: { "$data.buildResult": "SUCCESS" } }
    } },     
    { $sort: { "_id.day": 1, "_id.month": 1, "_id.year": 1 } } 
])
```

I have tried many variations with the following lines including $match, $in and other operators.  Any help would be very appreciated.

```
aborted: { $sum: { "$data.buildResult": "ABORTED" } },
failure: { $sum: { "$data.buildResult": "FAILURE" } },
unstable: { $sum: { "$data.buildResult": "UNSTABLE" } },
success: { $sum: { "$data.buildResult": "SUCCESS" } }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To achieve that you can use the [$cond](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/) and [$eq](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/eq/) operators like this:

```
aborted: {$sum: {$cond : [{$eq : ["$data.buildResult", "ABORTED"]}, 1, 0]}}
```

**Edit:**
As noted by [Neil Lunn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2313887/neil-lunn) in the comments, the $cond here is irrelevant because the $eq operator already returns 0 or 1.

```
aborted: {$sum: {$eq : ["$data.buildResult", "ABORTED"]}}
```

Comment: @JimG also you may have your sorted flipped :) { $sort: { "_id.year": 1, "_id.month": 1, "_id.day": 1 } }

Comment: @joao Actually `$eq` by itself will return either 1 or 0 thus making the `$cond` irrelevant. Just for future notice.

Comment: @NeilLunn Nice, didn't know it could be used like that. Thanks.

Comment: For people coming in ~2021 (and/or on Mongo 4.4.5), I had to use toInt as well, e.g.: 
`aborted: {$sum: {$toInt: {$eq : ["$data.buildResult", "ABORTED"]}}}`